# Display pdf's in responsive used in embed tag

Tags: jquery, pdf, jquery-mobile, joomla3.0, responsive

I have a website kindly check the link:- 
http://blufysh.com/hcs/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23:study-of-dada-parsi-colony-and-khodaddad-circle-precincts&catid=15&Itemid=119

The website is built on joomla in which i used embed tag in articles with Tiny editor
.

if am trying to view the pdf in responsive (320px X 540px) resolution i am unable to view the pdf and also in mobile devices.

How do i display pdf in mobile devices and responsive resolutions.
any help??

Answer (score 0):

This works and its responsive.

```html
<style>
   .embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>

<div class='embed-container'>
 <iframe id='frame' src='MyPDF'></iframe>
  </div>
```